# byte string vs. unicode string. Python

Tags: python, string, unicode

Could you explain in detail what the difference is between byte string and Unicode string in Python. I have read [this](http://www.coolinterview.com/interview/5512/):

> Byte code is simply the converted source code into arrays of bytes

Does it mean that Python has its own coding/encoding format? Or does it use the operation system settings?
I don't understand. Could you please explain?
Thank you!

Comment: coolinterview.com looks like a terrible source of information. I would not rely on it.

Comment: "Byte code" usually refers to something completely different, http://docs.python.org/glossary.html "Python source code is compiled into bytecode, the internal representation of a Python program in the CPython interpreter. The bytecode is also cached in .pyc and .pyo files"

Comment: +1 dbr's comment. Bytecode is an internal CPython implementation detail which isn't related to Unicode and you probably don't have to worry about.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No, Python does not use its own encoding - it will use any encoding that it has access to and that you specify.

A character in a `str` represents one Unicode character. However, to represent more than 256 characters, individual Unicode encodings use more than one byte per character to represent many characters.

`bytes` objects give you access to the underlying bytes. `str` objects have the `encode` method that takes a string representing an encoding and returns the `bytes` object that represents the string in that encoding. `bytes` objects have the `decode` method that takes a string representing an encoding and returns the `str` that results from interpreting the `byte` as a string encoded in the the given encoding.

For example:

```
>>> a = "αά".encode('utf-8')
>>> a
b'\xce\xb1\xce\xac'
>>> a.decode('utf-8')
'αά'
```

We can see that UTF-8 is using four bytes, `\xce`, `\xb1`, `\xce`, and `\xac`, to represent two characters.

Related reading:

- [Python Unicode Howto](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/howto/unicode.html) (from the official documentation)
- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- [Pragmatic Unicode](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

Answer (score 35):

Here's an attempt at a simple explanation that only applies to Python 3. I hope that coming from a lay person, it would help to clear some confusion for the completely uninitiated. If there are any technical inaccuracies, please forgive me and feel free to point it out.

Suppose you create a string using Python 3 in the usual way:

```
stringobject = 'ant'
```

`stringobject` would be a unicode string.

A unicode string is made up of unicode characters. In `stringobject` above, the unicode characters are the individual letters, e.g. a, n, t

Each unicode character is assigned a code point, which can be expressed as a sequence of hex digits (a hex digit can take on 16 values, ranging from 0-9 and A-F). For instance, the letter `'a'` is equivalent to `'\u0061'`, and 'ant' is equivalent to `'\u0061\u006E\u0074'`.

So you will find that if you type in,

```
stringobject = '\u0061\u006E\u0074'
stringobject
```

You will also get the output `'ant'`.

Now, **unicode is converted to bytes**, in a process known as **encoding**. The reverse process of **converting bytes to unicode** is known as **decoding**.

How is this done? Since each hex digit can take on 16 different values, it can be reflected in a 4-bit binary sequence (e.g. the hex digit 0 can be expressed in binary as 0000, the hex digit 1 can be expressed as 0001 and so forth). If a unicode character has a code point consisting of four hex digits, it would need a 16-bit binary sequence to encode it.

Different encoding systems specify different rules for converting unicode to bits. Most importantly, encodings differ in the number of bits they use to express each unicode character.

For instance, the ASCII encoding system uses only 8 bits (1 byte) per character. Thus it can only encode unicode characters with code points up to two hex digits long (i.e. 256 different unicode characters). The UTF-8 encoding system uses 8 to 32 bits (1 to 4 bytes) per character, so it can encode unicode characters with code points up to 8 hex digits long, i.e. everything.

Running the following code:

```
byteobject = stringobject.encode('utf-8')
byteobject, type(byteobject)
```

converts a unicode string into a byte string using the utf-8 encoding system, and returns `b'ant', bytes'`.

Note that if you used 'ASCII' as the encoding system, you wouldn't run into any problems since all code points  in 'ant' can be expressed with 1 byte. But if you had a unicode string containing characters with code points longer than two hex digits, you would get a `UnicodeEncodeError`.

Similarly,

```
stringobject = byteobject.decode('utf-8')
stringobject, type(stringobject)
```

gives you `'ant', str`.

Comment: (1) In general, a user-perceived character such as `g̈` may correspond to several Unicode codepoints (U+0067 U+0308 in this case). (2) the encoding of a Unicode codepoint may be unrelated to its number i.e., 8-bit encoding may represent ~0x100 characters, it is not necessary that all these characters must be *consecutive* (it is not necessary that *"a code point consisting of four hex digits, it would need a 16-bit binary sequence to encode it"* -- it doesn't make sense to talk about the size required to encode a single codepoint -- only a set of characters imposes restrictions)

Comment: ASCII is a 7 bit encoding, not 8 bit. Try, eg, `chr(128).encode('ascii')` and you'll get an encoding error.