# NLTK (python) and Greek encoding

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, nlp, nltk

I try to use NLTK pagkage in Greek text and I deal with a great problem with the encoding. My code is below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, string, re, nltk

def find_bigrams(input_list):
   bigram_list = []
   for i in range(len(input_list)-1):
       bigram_list.append((input_list[i], input_list[i+1]))
       return bigram_list

def get_nice_string(list_or_iterator):
   return "[" + " , ".join( str(x) for x in list_or_iterator) + "]"

def stripText(rawText):
   text = rawText
    rules = [
    {r'{[^)]*\}' : ''},             # remove curly brackets
    {r'\([^)]*\)' : ''},            # remove parentheses
    {r'^https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*' : ''},# remove urls
    {r' +' : ' '},                  # remove multiple whitespaces
    {r'^\s+': ''},                  # remove whitespaces beginning
    {r'\.\.+' : '.'}                # remove multiple fullstops
    ]

for rule in rules:
    for (k, v) in rule.items():
        regex = re.compile(k)
        text = regex.sub(v, text)

sentenceClean = text.translate(string.maketrans('', ''), '{}[]|?"=\'')
return sentenceClean

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = open('C:\\Users\\Dimitris\\Desktop\\1.txt', 'r').readlines()

    newFile = open('C:\\Users\\Dimitris\\Desktop\\corpus.txt', 'w')
    newFile1 = open('C:\\Users\\Dimitris\\Desktop\\words.txt', 'w')

    words = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'File', 'Image']

for line in f:
    sentences = stripText(line)
    whitespaces = sentences.count(' ')
    if any(word in sentences for word in words):
        continue
    elif whitespaces < 20:
        continue
    else:
        newFile.write(sentences+'\n')

        b = nltk.word_tokenize(sentences)
        print get_nice_string(b)
        get_nice_string(nltk.bigrams(b))
        print get_nice_string(nltk.bigrams(b))

        newFile1.write(get_nice_string(b))


newFile.close()
newFile1.close()
```

When I try to print the output from nltk.word_tokenize(sentences), the result is like something that (('\xe5\xe3\xea\xfe\xec\xe9\xe1', '\xe3\xe9')), but if I use the  get_nice_string() function and I turn list into a string, then the result is normal greek text. 
So far so good.

But whether I use find_bigrams() function or nltk.bigrams() I get strings like the above (('\xe5\xe3\xea\xfe\xec\xe9\xe1', '\xe3\xe9')), even if I use get_nice_string() function, in order to turn list into string.

Also, I have tried to open file with the codecs.open() function, like this

```
f = codecs.open('C:\\Users\\Dimitris\\Desktop\\1.txt', 'r', 'utf-8').readlines()
```

but the problem persists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, NLTK's `word_tokenize()` might not suit the Greek data you've input; the default `nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize()` is trained on the English Penn Treebank, see https://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.tokenize.treebank.TreebankWordTokenizer-class.html

I'm not sure whether you're getting the right tokenization but since greek uses whitespaces as token delimiters, NLTK might seem to work but I would have use `str.split()` instead:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> x = "Θέλεις να χορέψεις μαζί μου"
>>> for i in word_tokenize(x):
...     print i
... 
Θέλεις
να
χορέψεις
μαζί
μου
>>> for i in x.split():
...     print i
... 
Θέλεις
να
χορέψεις
μαζί
μου
```

Rather than using the default `word_tokenize()` in NLTK, it would be better if you just retrain a punkt model using `PunktTrainer` http://nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktTrainer

Next about printing `utf8` characters, see [byte string vs. unicode string. Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060411/byte-string-vs-unicode-string-python)

Lastly the problem of NLTK messing up your bigrams, I suggest using your own bigrams code since NLTK is tested largely on English inputs and not greek, try:

```
>>> x = "Θέλεις να χορέψεις μαζί μου"
>>> bigrams = zip(*[x.split()[i:] for i in range(2)])
>>> for i in bigrams:
...     print i[0], i[1]
... 
Θέλεις να
να χορέψεις
χορέψεις μαζί
μαζί μου
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But my problem persists, when I import text from .txt file. I have no problem using the terminal. Also, I can see the word with decoding like

`code`>>> print '\xce\x9a\xce\xac\xce\xb9\xcf\x81\xce\xbf'.decode('utf-8')
Κάιρο`code`

I'm afraid that the problem is related with the fact that nltk.bigrams() returns tubles inside a list. But i can't still find a solution.

Comment: Thy to use this: `f = codecs.open('C:\\Users\\Dimitris\\Desktop\\1.txt', 'r', 'utf-8-sig').readlines()`