# Encoding: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Tags: python, json

I have a rudimentary grasp of python but am not clear on dealing with binary encoding issues. I am trying to run sample code from a firefox-webextensions example in which a python script sends text that is read by a javascript program. I keep encountering encoding errors.

The python code is:

```
#! /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5
import sys, json, struct

text = "pong"

encodedContent = json.dumps(text)
encodedLength = struct.pack('@I', len(encodedContent))
encodedMessage = {'length': encodedLength, 'content': encodedContent}

sys.stdout.write(encodedMessage['length'])
sys.stdout.write(encodedMessage['content'])
```

The error trace (displayed in firefox console) is:

```
stderr output from native app chatX: Traceback (most recent call last):
stderr output from native app chatX: File "/Users/inchem/Documents/firefox addons/py/chatX.py", line 10, in <module>
stderr output from native app chatX: sys.stdout.write(encodedMessage['length'])
stderr output from native app chatX: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Running python 3.5.1 on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6, x86 64bit cpu; firefox developer ed 52.0

The python script I am using, as shown above, is minimized from the original at
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging

I also tried:

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write(encodedMessage['length'])
sys.stdout.buffer.write(encodedMessage['content'])
```

which generated:

```
stderr output from native app chatX: sys.stdout.buffer.write(encodedMessage['content'])
stderr output from native app chatX: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: have you tried to convert it to string like the following?sys.stdout.buffer.write(str(encodedMessage['length']))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example was probably Python 2-compliant, but things have changed in Python 3.

You are generating a binary representation of the length as *bytes* with this:

```
encodedLength = struct.pack('@I', len(encodedContent))
```

It is not printable. You can write it through a socket stream which is a binary stream but not through `stdout` which is a text stream.

The trick of using `buffer` (as explained in [How to write binary data in stdout in python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908331/how-to-write-binary-data-in-stdout-in-python-3)) is good but only for the binary part (note that you get the error message for the text part now):

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write(encodedMessage['length'])
```

For the text part, just write to `stdout`:

```
sys.stdout.write(encodedMessage['content'])
```

or use `sys.stdout.buffer` with string to bytes conversion:

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write(bytes(encodedMessage['content'],"utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to ensure your input is str (unicode) before writing to stdout / stderr.

in your example:

```
sys.stdout.write(encodedMessage['length'].decode('utf8'))
sys.stdout.write(encodedMessage['content'])
```

you can see that `type(encodedLength))` is `bytes` while `type(encodedContent)` is `str`.

please read [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34695423/7438048) for more info about bytes vs string in python3.X

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks.