# How to get Chrome Native Messaging example to work with Python script on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am trying to get the Chrome Native Messaging example found [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to work. I have had to make some changes to the host script to work with Python 3.

I successfully ran the `install_host.sh` file which created the file `/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/NativeMessagingHosts/com.google.chrome.example.echo.json`. This file correctly contains the path to the python host file.

**Changes to example**

I have edited the host file as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41795409/encoding-typeerror-write-argument-must-be-str-not-bytes) to fix the issues relating to the type. The send message function now reads

```
def send_message(message):
    encodedContent = json.dumps(message)
    encodedLength = struct.pack('@I', len(encodedContent))
    encodedMessage = {'length': encodedLength, 'content': encodedContent}
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(encodedMessage['length'])
    sys.stdout.write(encodedMessage['content'])
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

**Problem**

I think the issue is connecting the chrome application to the python script. When i run the the chrome extension at `chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/main.html` i get this error

```
Connecting to native messaging host com.google.chrome.example.echo

Failed to connect: Specified native messaging host not found.
```

Could anyone please advise as to what step i might be missing in order to get the Chrome web extension to send and receive messages to the python script.

Comment: The "user-specific" path should be inside the user directory e.g. `~/Library/........`

Comment: the path is actually the full path to the file, i just removed my username when sharing on here

Comment: sorry my mistake the path to the file is `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/NativeMessagingHosts/com.google.chrome.example.echo.json` but the path inside the json file contains the relative path to the python script.

Comment: The documentation says "On Linux and OSX the `path` [in json] must be absolute".

Comment: i changed to an absolute path but have the same error

Comment: Try restarting the browser. Try [enabling logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) and inspect the result.