# Python 3 strings are Unicode strings, not byte arrays

Tags: python

I read the following sentence in book "introducing python"

> Python 3 strings are Unicode strings, not byte arrays. This is the single largest change from Python 2, which distinguished between normal byte strings and Unicode character strings.

I am very confused here, I tested respectively in python3 and python2

in python 3

```
In [12]: s = "python3"
In [13]: type(s)
Out[13]: str
```

In python2:

```
>>> s = "python2"
>>> type(s)
<type 'str'>
```

They are of the identical type.

How could I find the description "byte arrays" in "python2"?

Comment: Strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060411/byte-string-vs-unicode-string-python

Comment: The fact that the type of a string is named `str` in both Python 2 and Python 3 means nothing for whether those strings are Unicode or bytestrings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [byte string vs. unicode string. Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060411/byte-string-vs-unicode-string-python)