# Cloud function attribute error: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'get' when reading json file from cloud storage

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts

I'm trying to read a JSON key file from Google Cloud Storage to authenticate. I have the following function:

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = 'bucket_name'
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.get_blob('key.json')
json_data_string = blob.download_as_string()

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(
    json_data_string,
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit'])
```

and the following error: `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'get'`

How should I read/format my `key.json` file to use it with `ServiceAccountCredentials`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `download_as_string()` function returns bytes, but `from_json_keyfile_dict()` expects a `dict`. You need to first decode the bytes to turn it into a string:

```
json_data_string = blob.download_as_string().decode('utf8')
```

And then load this string as a `dict`:

```
import json
json_data_dict = json.loads(json_data_string)
```

And then you can call:

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(
    json_data_dict,
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit'])
```

Comment: What are bytes exactly? Is there a way to directly access json file from storage in the proper format?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060411/byte-string-vs-unicode-string-python. The "proper format" is subjective here, Cloud Storage just stores binary blobs, so it's up to you to turn it into the format you're expecting it to be.

Comment: Ok. so whatever I extract from Cloud Storage it will always be binary blobs.